# How to update the apt-check count of “X packages can be updated” message

Tags: linux, bash, apt

Is there a command to update the apt-check results?

I run upgrade and it shows 0 but apt-check still shows 12 packages can be updated. How often is this suppose to update on its own? I have numerous servers. Some seem to update instantly. Others go days still showing updates are available when they aren't.

```
# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove
# /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
12 packages can be updated.
9 updates are security updates.
```

Comment: I've seen that count update after a selective upgrade. What I think the problem is that it counts differently somehow, though I'd sure think you apt-get upgrade would've covered everything...

Answer (score 0):

I'm still investigating this myself, but it appears that:

- this is supposed to update automatically via `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99update-notifier`
- `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available --force` should do the update you want manually.
- `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable` actually generates the output in question.

At least some of the above must be wrong though, or require more configuration than I have so far understood, since on my systems, the `motd` text is not being automatically updated when package updates run.